# How can I detect if a cookie exists using the Ruby programming language?

Tags: ruby, apache, cookies, cgi

I know how to read cookies using CGI and Ruby but the problem is, if I try to read cookies.value[0] when it does not exists, it breaks my program. So I need to check if the cookie is there to read first. I can't find this answer anywhere on the internet.

Please help, thank you,
Henry.

Answer (score 1):

The [Ruby CGI doc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/classes/CGI.html) says:

> HTTP Cookies are automatically parsed from the request. They are available from the cookies() accessor, which returns a hash from cookie name to CGI::Cookie object.

If that's the case, then the cookies are simply stored in a regular hash. You can use the regular [Hash API](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html) to check for the presence of the target cookie, including [Hash.key?()](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M002885):

```
if cgi.cookies().key?("mycookie")
  p "Cookie value is #{cgi.cookies()["mycookie"].value}"
else
  p "Cookie does not exist."
end
```

Comment: Would it be possible to show me a snippet of code to check if a cookie called 'mycookie' exists? I know in PHP you can use something like if(isset[cookiename])

Thanks for the answer

Comment: I actually was writing one up while you left that comment :-)

Comment: FYI: I wrote this example up freehand; I haven't actually ran it. It should be close enough to get you going, but be on the lookout for (minor) errors.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me using slim.

```
- if cookies().key?("cookieName")
  p Cookie value is #{cookies()["cookieName"]}
- else
  p "Cookie does not exist."
end
```

First will result in `true` if cookie present.